# i want to put static listview Item in fragment and make on click item on in how i can do that

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, onclick

```
public class FoodFragment  extends Fragment {
    static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Kia","Bmw","mercedes benz" };
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) { 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }  

         @Override  
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food, container, false);

            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
            inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  
            numbers_text);  
          setListAdapter(adapter);  
          return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);  
         }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this method

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

after your adapter set in ListView.

You need to change from

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_cars,Cars));
```

to

```
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_cars,Cars));
```

Comment: i have error in this   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_cars,Cars));

Comment: have you checked answer again?